# Javascript: Creating an Array of random math equations as objects, 20 times

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

[What it's supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMf9m.png)

I'm tasked with dynamically creating 20 math problems. The math problems must be created as an array of objects before they're rendered. The part I'm stuck on is creating 20 different random equations as objects in an array, and call them into table. Here is what I have so far.

```
<script>

    // creates a random number from 1-100
var randNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

var randNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

// creates a random operator
var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];


var problemList = [{number1: randNum1, operator: op, number2: randNum2},

];



var problems, i;


var displayProblems = function (problems) {
    // open the table
    var str = "<table class=table>";

    for (i = 0; i < problems.length; i++) {
        str += "<tr>";
        str += "<td>" + problems[i].number1 + " " + problems[i].operator + " " + problems[i].number2 + " " + "<input type='text' class='answer' id='answer_" + i + "' /></td>";
        str += "</tr>";

    }

    str += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("mathGrid").innerHTML = str;
};

window.onload =function () {
    displayProblems(problemList);

};

</script>
```

I've been stuck on this all day, and cannot figure out how to do this. This is my second assignment for javascript, and any help would be much appreciated.

Here is an example of what I have in action.
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ian_A/s74f1Lew/#&togetherjs=TsKIM5jgTy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do when solving a problem like this, would be to simplify it.

Start by making a function that creates just a single random problem, like so:

```
function generateProblem() {
    // creates a random number from 1-100
    var randNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    var randNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

    // creates a random operator
    var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)];

    return {number1: randNum1, operator: op, number2: randNum2};
}
```

Notice that after having that function, you can already test it and see something working.

After that, making 20 of them is a lot easier, you just have to call the function 20 times and add the results to the array. Either by hand:

```
var problemList = [
    generateProblem(),
    generateProblem(),
    generateProblem()
    ...
];
```

Or using a loop:

```
var problemList = [];
while (problemList.length < 20) {
    problemList.push(generateProblem());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now is `var problemList` considered to be an array of objects? And would I still be able to call it in a for loop to print out 20 different problems?

The way you've broken it down is very helpful, and it's definitely easier than the way my book explains how to "try" it.

Comment: @Gorgon_Union Yes, it's still an array of objects, exactly the way it was before.